# How to build Next.JS apps that works on any web broswer

Tags: next.js, deployment, web-applications, vercel

I am new to web dev. I developed a NextJS app on my Ubuntu machine but when I deploy that on Vercel, I hear from iOS users that there are inconsistencies when they use different browsers. How can I resolve this? Should I dockerize the app?

The app works fine on Ubuntu (my laptop), but I hear iOS users have problems in both rendering and the functionality, what is the industry standard to tackle this problem?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.